# Use the data from input string as a set of variables

Tags: windows, batch

I want to extract some data from input string (e.g. name1,name2,name3...), and then use all of them as a variables (e.g. var1=name1, var2=name2, varN=nameN). The number of 'names' can be different. I want to apply a set of commands for these variables in a FOR loop later in the script.

Comment: Are the variables separated by commas in your input string?

Comment: yes, any deliminator actually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a "for each" loop like so:

```
set params=param1,param2,param3

for %%p in (%params%) do (
    :: do something with %%p
)
```

Aside from a comma `,`, the other valid delimiters are:

- a semicolon `;`
- an equals sign `=`
- a space character
- a tab character

---

### Example :

Script:

```
@echo off

set params=param1,param2,param3

for %%p in (%params%) do (
    echo %%p
)
```

Output:

```
param1
param2
param3
```